# VB.Net function pointer with fixed parameter values

Tags: vb.net, function, pointers

I have a custom-written background task manager that takes an Action as parameter, queues it, waits until an execution thread is free and then invokes it.

Now I wanted to do the following:

```
    Dim lValue As Integer = 0I
    For tIndex As Integer = 0 To 10
       BackgroundTaskManager.QueueTask(New Action(Sub() DoSomething(lValue)))
       lValue += 1
    Next
```

This obviously leads to some strange results, because the lambda expression is invoked at an unpredictable moment (whenever a thread is available), so the *DoSomething-method* does not have access to the actual value that I want it to have.

However, putting these parameters into to the sub - which would require an Action(Of T, ...) - is not really an option, because my background task manager only takes Action without parameters and I want it to stay that way (the background task manager should not have any knowledge about what's actually being called).

**What I'm looking for is a way to store a function pointer with parameter values already evaluated, ready to be invoked by a simple [FunctionWithParametersEvaluated].[Invoke].**

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you declare a local variable inside the loop, then assign `lValue` to that variable and use that variable as the lambda parameter then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Although I don't think it's very elegant.